# opencv for hydro medusa

Tags: opencv

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i am building an underwater vehicle so needed opencv to work with it for image processing . How do i use it  on hydro medusa . I am also new ros so could you tell me how to use opencv with it.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/127436/opencv-for-hydro-medusa/) by [deepak.shankar94](https://answers.ros.org/users/11771/deepak.shankar94/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-02-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

write the following lines in yor Cmake

> find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)

> target_link_libraries(executable ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES})

If you want to Converting between ROS images and OpenCV images please see [cv_bridge](http://wiki.ros.org/cv_bridge/Tutorials/UsingCvBridgeToConvertBetweenROSImagesAndOpenCVImages)

---

Originally posted by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) with karma: 1769 on 2014-02-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Athoesen](https://answers.ros.org/users/8296/athoesen/) on 2014-02-11**:
Hey Hamid, I haven't seen you in a bit.  Have you used cv_bridge a lot? After realizing the camera_pose_calibration package is broken, I started looking into OpenCV for processing the Kinect data streams.  Is this a path you would recommend?

**Comment by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) on 2014-02-11**:
Hey :) I do not use cv_bridge a lot.I just use it for converting between ROS images and OpenCV image Once.
If you want to use OpenCV with the depth data you can use cv_bridge to convert the ROS topic into an OpenCV cv::Mat.
I hope this helpful for you. :)